# Keeping floated divs inline

Tags: css, html, xhtml, css-float

I'm having trouble getting my layout working correctly, I have a main div and a sidebar div these are both `float: left` if the screen size is resized or if its viewed on  screen smaller that what I have designed on (1920x1080) then the sidebar div drops below the main content.

I tried placing a wrapper around each div, but this has no effect.

```
    <div id="header">       
        [Header]        
    </div>

    <div id="content">      
        [Content]       
    </div>

    <div id="sideBar">
        [SideBar]
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        [Footer]
    </div>

body
{   
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #000000; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #336699;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;   
}

#content
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 700px;  
    margin-top: 40px;       
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#sideBar
{
    float: left;    
    margin-left: 50px;  
    width: 15%; 
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
}

#footer
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #174555;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #ffffff; 
    clear: both;
}
```

Basicly both div's should resize until a certain size is reached, then scrolling should be enabled. I'm pretty sure I have done something simple wrong but i'm not much of a design person.

Example can be shown here : [Link](http://elliottstocks.co.uk/test)

Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karpie's right.

Also why not simply start out with one main div, say measuring 1000px in width, then work within that? If you can't do that then choose a measurement type, like px, and stick with for the widths, padding and margins of those elements. At least that would make it easier to do your math and know how much space you do or don't have.

I generally stick to relative measurements, like pixels (I don't like absolutes, it's personal. :P).

EDIT

Ok, try this, add a wrapper around the entire page (just to test, so bear with me). Give that wrapper an id of like #main-body or something, and define a width. Set the widths of the content and sidebar. If you minimize the screen, the sidebar shouldn't fall below the content div. It wil go outside the view port, though.

```
/* Wrap all in #main-body with specified width */

#main-body{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/* give these elements a relative width */

#content
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width:600px;
    height: 700px;  
    margin-top: 40px;       
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#sideBar
{
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    margin-left: 50px;  
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
}
```

Sorry for the length of this. :P

Comment: The sidebar needs to be outside the main div, thanks i'll give that ago.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your edit and it seems to work although I want the whole body to be filled, and if possible "squash" the div size until a min width before it starts to scroll? As scrolling starts with even a large screen size. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up percentages and pixels. 70% width + 30px padding + 50px margin (all on `content`) + 50px margin + 15% width + 30px padding (all on `sidebar`) can add up to more than 100%.